# Need help pulling values from JSON using python, getting TypeError

Tags: python, json, keyerror

Here's an example of the JSON I'm pulling from a URL:

```
[
{
    "externalModelId": "500A000000RQOwnIAH", 
    "resource": {
        "account": {
            "externalModelId": "001A000001EucpoIAB", 
            "resource": {
                "accountName": "Foobar", 
                "accountNumber": 1234567, 
            }, 
            "resourceReliability": "Fresh"
        }, 
        "caseNumber": 1234567, 
        "created": "2015-06-12T19:06:22.000Z", 
        "createdBy": {
            "externalModelId": "005A0000005mhdXIAQ", 
            "resourceReliability": "Fresh"
        }, 
        "description": "Example description", 
        "hoursInCurrentStatus": 406, 
        "internalPriority": "3 (Normal)", 
        "lastModified": "2015-06-22T14:08:18.000Z", 
        "owner": {
            "externalModelId": "005A0000001sKDzIAM", 
            "resourceReliability": "Fresh"
        }, 
        "product": {
            "resource": {
                "line": {
                    "externalModelId": 21118, 
                    "resource": {
                        "name": null
                    }, 
                    "resourceReliability": "Fresh"
                }, 
                "version": {
                    "externalModelId": 21988, 
                    "resource": {
                        "name": "1.2"
                    }, 
                    "resourceReliability": "Fresh"
                }
            }, 
            "resourceReliability": "Fresh"
        }, 
        "resourceCount": 0, 
        "sbrs": [
            "Value"
        ], 
        "sbt": 139, 
        "severity": "4 (Low)", 
        "status": "Status Example", 
        "subject": "Subject Example", 
        "tags": [
            "br", 
            "fs"
        ], 
        "targetDate": "2015-07-15T17:46:48.000Z", 
        "type": "Feature"
    }, 
    "resourceReliability": "Fresh"
},
```

I'm interested in pulling the following values from it:

- caseNumber
- subject
- severity
- sbt
- sbrs
- status

The code I currently have is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import sys
import requests
import json
import os

# Setup 
username = "XXX"
password = "XXX"
accountid = "12345"

# Formulate the string and then capture the output
url = "http://XXX{0}XXX{1}XXXXX".format(accountid, filedtime)
r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
parsed = json.loads(r.text)
parent = parsed['resource']

# Using json_string for testing
#json_string = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
#print json_string

for item in parent:
    print item['caseNumber']
    print item['subject']
    print item['severity']
    print item['sbt']
    print item['sbrs']
    print item['status']
```

The code outputs a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./newcase-notify.py", line 31, in <module>
    parent = parsed['resource']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I've tried specifying something like:

```
parent = parsed['resource'][0]['type']
```

but that doesn't work.  I think I'm confused at this point.  If I don't specify a parent and simply iterate through 'parsed' like:

```
for item in parsed:
    print item['caseNumber']
    print item['subject']
    print item['severity']
    print item['sbt']
    print item['sbrs']
    print item['status']
```

I get KeyError's again.

### My Question:

Given the information provided, how can I pull the above mentioned values from my JSON object?

Comment: could you try print parsed[item]['caseNumber']

Comment: you don't seem to know python. `for item in parent:` is iterating the keys, not the items. i admit python is not intuitive on this, but it's obvious you don't know very basic python.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by removing:

```
parent = parsed['resource']
```

and using:

```
for item in parsed:
    print item['resource']['caseNumber']
    print item['resource']['subject']
    print item['resource']['severity']
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the top of your JSON you'll notice this:

```
[
{
```

That means an array, with an object inside. You need to dereference that object form the array first. Hence why you're getting that jazz about list indices must be of type integer and not string. Once you do that it should work.

`parent = parsed[0]['resource']` should fix you right up.

Just to help guide you with translating between the nomenclatures:
Array:JS as List:Python and Object:JS as Dict:Python.